# Is there a way how to count commits on remote repository using libgit2 in c++?

Tags: c++, git-commit, libgit2

I would like to count commits on a remote repository, because I want to compare it with the number of commits in my local clone. Is there a way how to get that count?

Comment: `git shortlog -s -n` ?

Comment: I need to do that via libgit2 in cpp, not in cmd

Answer (score -1):

You can ref. to [git_reflog_entrycount](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/reflog/git_reflog_entrycount).

Comment: While links are great, questions should quote relevant sections of the referenced material and explain how it answers the question.